# ERROR TypeError: (moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___namespace_cache || moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___namespace_cache) is not a function

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular14upgrade

I was migrating my angular 11 app to angular 14. I had a custom npm package that used moment 2.29.3. i also had the same moment package installed in app also. Now i am getting following console error in the app where i am using the npm package

ERROR TypeError: (moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___namespace_cache || moment__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___namespace_cache) is not a function

tried various solution mentioned in the following posts
[using Moment with Angular library 13 causes an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595835/using-moment-with-angular-library-13-causes-an-error)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71038799

Comment: If it is duplicate, consider to follow up the same post.

Comment: @Akshay could you be able to fix this issue? I am having the same issue after migrate angular 12 to 13.